# executable generated from pyinstaller it's not working

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I'm doing a program responsible for managing a bookstore and I'm at the end of it. I'm creating the executable from it, but it's giving an error when running I don't know what it is.

Error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 3494, in <module>
  File "db_manager.py", line 278, in titulo_livros
  File "pandas\io\parsers.py", line 605, in read_csv
  File "pandas\io\parsers.py", line 457, in _read
  File "pandas\io\parsers.py", line 814, in __init__
  File "pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1045, in _make_engine
  File "pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1862, in __init__
  File "pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1357, in _open_handles
  File "pandas\io\common.py", line 642, in get_handle
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'livros.csv'
[432] Failed to execute script main
```

The command I am using to generate the exe file is "pyinstaller --onefile main.py".

And that is my tree folder:

[my tree folder project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pGSjW.png)

Please help me, i have no idea of what is going on.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: "i have no idea of what is going on" Well, do you suppose perhaps where it says `No such file or directory: 'livros.csv'`, that might be trying to tell you what is going on? What do you suppose that part means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

somewhere you are doing `pandas.read_csv(fname)` where `fname='livros.csv'`

you need to give it the right path to the csv (or bundle the csv into the executable ... but that probably doesnt make sense, im not sure why you would ever bundle the csv into the executable)

after alot of back and forth I think this is what you want

```
import os
import pandas
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
db_path = os.path.expanduser('~/my_file.db')
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///'+db_path, echo=False)

try:
    existing = pandas.read_sql('SELECT title, author FROM books', engine)
except:
    existing = pandas.DataFrame({'title':['Title 1','Title 2'],'author':['Bob Roberts','Sam Spade']})
print("DBPATH:",db_path)
# ... do some stuff (add/edit/remove items from your dataframe)
existing.to_sql("books",engine)
```

Comment: this part of the code is a function that has this code:

df = pd.read_csv('livros.csv')

titulos = df['titulo'].unique().astype(str).tolist()

return titulos

Comment: i think that my mistake is that i probably not passing the csv files in the pyinstaller command. am i right?

Comment: you should probably accept the csv path as a command line argument (sys.argv) or prompt the user with a filedialog ... i dont understand why you would want to hardcode the exact csv everytime ... there are more efficient datastructures if its always the exact same data... even including it in the datas section for pyinstaller probably wont let you get the path with just 'livros.csv' you will need to use something like `os.path.join(sys._MEIPASS,'livros.csv')`  which will ONLY work within a pyinstaller executable (or you will need some smarter logic)

Comment: i'm doing with a csv file because when i was doing with sqlite i couldn't update, and i don't know why and didn't return any error, i have no idea of what i can do

Comment: wich datastructures do you recommend man? i'm desperate

Comment: sqlite is almost guaranteed to be the right answer for something like this .... and it did work ... but if your database is created in the temp folder (where your executable actually unpacks and runs from) then it is likely getting destroyed when it goes away ... try and use sqlite with a db_path of something like `os.path.expanduser("~/myDB.sqlite3")` that will create your database in the users home folder  ... if you want to update records that is ... if its just a hardcoded list ... just include it as a list of strings...

Comment: When I was using sqlite I created the database through the constructor of a class, do you think that's why it didn't update the data? If it is, how should i create and call the database?

Comment: `db = sqlite3.connect(os.path.expanduser("~/my_bookstore.sqlite3"))` should work fine (it will create the db file in the users directory, so a different user would not get the same db but thats probably fine)...  you will have to do something like `db.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS bookstore (title CHAR),...")` right after you connect

Comment: Ok man, i'll try it tomorrow morning. Can i talk to you in your chat to help me with this? I never did this connection, this is new to me.

Comment: how were you doing your database before when it did not work?

Comment: `db = sqlite3.connect('my_bookstore.db')` and when i used that way i just could add new records

Comment: no you cant you need a table in the database to add records to ... so it has to either already exist in the file ... or sqlite3.connect will create an empty database if the file doesnt exist, but you need a table to write the records to ... hmm i take that back maybe pandas does this for you ... follow this tutorial https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html ... but use `os.path.expanduser('sqlite3:///~/my_file.db')` instead of the inmemory db

Comment: `db.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS bookstore (title CHAR),...")` i did this in the constructor but i didn't make the connection as you told above. What is the name of that type of connection that you made? and can you recommend me any website that help me to understand that type of connection?

Comment: @JhosefMatheus I edited the answer to provide an actual answer... with code :P

Comment: oh sorry kkkkkk, but the point is that's new for me, i would like to understand it, i don't know why this way you told the update works, understand?

Comment: Please note that Stack Overflow is *not a discussion forum*. Please do not use the comment section for extended discussion. There is a chat feature attached to the site; or if you really need to talk the problem through with someone, try using an actual discussion forum such as Reddit or Quora.